# Copy site collection from one web application to another web application within the same farm

Tags: site-collection, backup, restore, 2016, move

I have two web applications, webapp1 and webapp2 in SharePoint 2016. Each one contains a root site collection. I need to copy the site collection from webapp1 to webapp2 as a site collection.

I tried different methods like: Backup and restore, but that gave me some errors.
Moving content database from one webapp to another, but then I mounted the database, it was showing 0 sites collections.

Anyone has got some good scripts which can do exactly what I am asking?

I followed the steps in this Technet page: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262792.aspx

**Mount-SpContentDatabase**

```
Dismount-SPContentDatabase WSS_Content_DB1

Mount-SPContentDatabase WSS_Content_DB1 -DatabaseServer spsql01 -WebApplication http://webapptest.aston.local
```

**Using Copy-SPSite**

```
Copy-SPSite http://spapp01:4696 -DestinationDatabase WSS_Content_DB1 -TargetUrl http://webapptest.aston.local
```

Comment: how did you try to backup? what version of sharepoint are you using?

Comment: Could you please share the errors and steps you followed

Comment: It is sharepoint 2016

Answer (score 3):

Use Backup-SPSite/Restore-SPSite. This method will generate a new Site ID for the restored site so you can use it within the same farm (sites within farms must have unique IDs).

Comment: Is it possible to user Restore-SPSite to restore the content dabase for a site collection which is not the root site collection?
This content database has to be used by a site collection which is secondary.

Comment: That question doesn't make sense. You can take a backup of a site collection and restore it to any location/content database associated with the web application you want.

Comment: suppose I do a backup the content database directly from SQL Server and I restore the db in another farm. How can I attach this content database to this site collection, for example: http://dev2/sites/secondsite ?

Comment: You don't. You attach a Content Database to a Web Application. Those Site Collections will then be associated with that Web Application.